# How to set the same height in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Below is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ib"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ib"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ImageButton ib and TextView tw has different height.
I want the ib and tv had the same height.
That is if height of ib > tv, then set the height of tv same as ib.
If else, then set the height of ib same as tv.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LinearLayout and set `ImageButton` height to `"wrap_content"` and for `TextView` set height to `"fill_parent"`.

Comment: Is it possible in RelativeLayout?

Comment: I dont think it is possible using RelativeLayout. If you use relative layout you have to specify the maxHieght of ImageButton so that it never stretch the ImageButton to image height.

Answer (score 17):

add `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_icon"` property to textview

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make the **height** of `ImageButton` is `"wrap_content"` and have the `TextView` just `"fill_parent"`. You will need to have them both wrapped in a layout parent. That way they are associated with the same layout parent.

Comment: But the parent RelativeLayout height is wrap_content. It will cause the height full screen?

Comment: No...RelativeLayout height is wrap_content means RelativeLayout height will depends on height of contents(ImageButton,TextView,etc..) in it...

Answer (score 0):

**Put your elements into LinearLayout, set layout_width="match_parent" and add properties "layout_weight"="1"**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sample text"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sample text"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sample text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```